# How to get DI from "top component" inside child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, hierarchy, web-component

[From Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#how-do-i-restrict-service-scope-to-a-module):

> Create a "top component" that acts as the root for all of the module's
>   components. Add the custom HttpBackend provider to the top component's
>   providers list rather than the module's providers. Recall that Angular
>   creates a child injector for each component instance and populates the
>   injector with the component's own providers.
>
> When a child of this component asks for the HttpBackend service,
>   Angular provides the local HttpBackend service, not the version
>   provided in the application root injector. Child components make
>   proper http requests no matter what other modules do to HttpBackend.
>
> Be sure to create module components as children of this module's top
>   component.

If we open source files for documentation of [Hierarchical Dependency Injectors](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-specialized-providers), we can see that `ACarComponent`, `BCarComponent` and `CCarComponent` creates three different instances of `CarService`, `CarService2` and `CarService3`.

But how I can to get `CarService` from parent DI for child component `BCarComponent` if I have also provide `CarService` on module level?

Comment: _But how I can to get parent DI from child component_ - what do you mean? what is your use case? do you define providers on components or modules?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, as you can see on quote - I defined provider on "top component' and I want get DI from this point for inner child component.

Comment: do you want to skip all intermediate component injectors? why are you not defining the provider at the module level as Suren recommends?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, I learn documentation (see link above) and I want to know how I can to get singleton from "top component", not from module level.

Comment: you can't do that with available public API

Answer (score 5):

If you will not give a provider for `CCarComponent`, it will go and try to get that provider instance from his parent component and so on.

Let's see an example.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'a-car-comp',
   template: '<div><b-car-comp></b-car-comp></div>',
   providers: [CarService]
})
class ACarComponent { 
    constructor(private carService: CarService) {}
}


@Component({
   selector: 'b-car-comp',
   template: '<div><c-car-comp></c-car-comp></div>'
})
class BCarComponent { 
    constructor(private carService: CarService) {}
}

@Component({
   selector: 'c-car-comp',
   template: '<div></div>'
})
class CCarComponent { 
    constructor(private carService: CarService) {}
}
```

Here I inject an instance of `CarService` into A, B and C Car components. In B and C components I have not provide their own `CarService` (providers list is empty) so it goes to his parent component (which uses it in his template) and get the same instance.

Each component which wants an instance of a service first tries to find in it's own providers, if not found, goes to upper component and tries to find there and so till to the root component (here `upper component` is that one which uses current component in it's template). If it is not found there too, Angular throws an

> Error: No Provider found for YourService

Comment: Yes, but so we can climb up to the root DI. But how we can climb up only for "top component" scope?

Comment: See the edited part. You need to ***not give** your service into the providers for that component

Comment: I was edited my question for clarify. As far as I understand, I will not be able to get DI at the `CCarComponent` level if I have same provider `CarService` at the module level.